# Was Pharoah killed in the Red Sea?

Tags: exodus

Was Pharoah killed in the Red Sea along with his army? I can't find any reference to this in exodus. Only mention of pharoahs chariots, horses, and army killed but not him. Popular believe presumes he was killed too. Is this the case?